# What is the difference between spring cloud config server exec.jar and .jar suffix

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

We are currently using spring cloud config server spring-cloud-config-server-1.1.0.M2-exec.jar and would like to upgrade to the latest version. However, i've noticed that beyond 1.1.0.M2 version there's only standard jars and no exec.jar in Maven repo http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-config-server/

Could someone please explain what the difference is? Will I be able to just substitute the exec one with the standard non exec one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exec jar contains an executable version of the config server (as a Spring Boot application). The non-exec jar contains only the config server classes. So you can't just replace the exec jar with the other one. What you basically have to do is to create a basic Spring Boot application with the config server dependencies and the appropriate annotations (like in [the example](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver)):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm that will require us changing all our spring boot applications. Is there any reason why the executable version is no longer available for versions beyond 1.1.0.M2? I just want to update that..

Comment: Why would that require changing all your applications? Basically what i posted will result in the same as the exec jar provided. The snippet which i posted should be within your config server application, not in all your other applications.